# Calculating weekly salary - Total value not correct

Tags: java

Here are my assignment details:

Write a Java program that can be used to calculate the weekly salary for hourly paid employees. The
program initially accepts the employee’s id, the number of hours worked, and the hourly pay rate. An
employee may work additional hours. When this happens, the additional number of hours must be
added to the original amount, and the salary is re-calculated. The program must output on separate
lines the employee’s id number, the number of hours worked, the hourly pay rate, and the salary, for
each employee. In addition, the program must also output the total amount of money paid out by the
company

Here is what I have so far

package payroll;

```
public class Payroll 
    {

    private static double TotalPayout;  
    private double Hours;
    private double Hourly_Rate;
    private String EmployeeId;
    public static double Salary;
    private double increaseHours = 10;

public Payroll (String getEmployeeId, double getHours, double 
getHourly_Rate)
    {
    EmployeeId = getEmployeeId;
    Hours = getHours;
    Hourly_Rate = getHourly_Rate;
    Salary = Hours * Hourly_Rate;

    TotalPayout = TotalPayout + Salary;
    }

public static double getTotalPayout()
    {
    return TotalPayout;
    }

public String getEmployeeId ()
    {
    return EmployeeId;
    }
public double getHours ()
    {
    return Hours;
    }
public void increaseHours (double x)
    {
    Hours = increaseHours + Hours;
    }
public double getHourly_Rate()
    {
    return Hourly_Rate;
    }
public double calculateSalary()
    {
    Salary = Hours * Hourly_Rate; 
    return Salary;
    }
    }   


package payroll;


import java.util.Date;//Used for creating a Date object
import java.text.DateFormat;//Used for specifying the format of the date
import java.text.NumberFormat;//Used for specifying the type of currency


public class TestPayroll 
{

public static void main (String [] arg)
{
    //Set up the formatters
    Date d = new Date();
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();


    System.out.println("ABC Company");
    System.out.println ("\nPayroll For Week Ending " + df.format (d));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

    //Define employee 1

    Payroll employee1 = new Payroll ("444-4444", 30, 25);
    employee1.calculateSalary();
    displaySalary (employee1, nf);

    //Define employee 2

    Payroll employee2 = new Payroll ("555-55555", 20, 50);
    employee2.calculateSalary();
    displaySalary(employee2, nf);

    System.out.println("\tIncrease " + employee1.getEmployeeId() + " by 10 
    hours");
    employee1.increaseHours(10); // 10 hours increase
    System.out.println("\tEmployee # ...... " + employee1.getEmployeeId ());
    System.out.println("\tHours Worked:.... " + employee1.getHours() + " 
    hours");
    System.out.println("\tHourly Rate:..... " + nf.format(employee1.getHourly_Rate()) + "/hour");
    System.out.println("\tYour Salary is .. " + nf.format(employee1.Salary));
    System.out.println("\t------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Total Payout Amount..... " + nf.format(Payroll.getTotalPayout()));
    System.out.println("-------------End of Report------------");
}
public static void displaySalary (Payroll e, NumberFormat nf)
{
    System.out.println("\tEmployee # ...... " + e.getEmployeeId ());
    System.out.println("\tHours Worked .... " + e.getHours() + " hours");
    System.out.println("\tHourly Rate ..... " + nf.format(e.getHourly_Rate()) + "/hour");
    System.out.println("\tYour Salary is .. " + nf.format(e.calculateSalary()));
    System.out.println("\t------------------------------\n");

}
}
```

Comment: don't just code dump, minimise your question and tell us what you have done and what you're struggling with.

Comment: Using floating point for exact money values is naughty. Work in cents with an integral type.

Comment: Properties should be lower case btw

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no programming experience, just going by what my prof has shown us. My issue is in the total payout calculation. It's coming up as $1750, instead of adding up to $2000. My total payout isn't reflecting the added 10 hours for employee 1.

Comment: Because you call the increaseHours method after you have calculated the salary.

Comment: @Christine has your professor taught you about `static` fields? Basically you should avoid them. The problem here is that `TotalPayout` is not being adjusted after you call `increaseHours` on employee2. A better way would be to not represent `TotalPayout` as a static at all... and calculate totalpayout from `employee1.getSalary() + employee2.getSalary()`

Comment: @vikingsteve From what I'm understanding, he's wanting us to use them. I'm not sure what you mean about calling? Am I supposed to change the order?

Comment: Please migrate codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this method.

```
public void increaseHours (double x)
{
    Hours = increaseHours + Hours;
}
```

Firstly, you are using the wrong field (`increaseHours`) instead of `x`. So please delete this line:

```
private double increaseHours = 10;
```

And now update your method:

```
public void increaseHours (double increaseHours)
{
    Hours = increaseHours + Hours;
    TotalPayout += increaseHours * Hourly_Rate;
}
```

This will fix your problem for now but I highly suggest *not* using a `static` field for `TotalPayout` - which will require you to redesign slightly.

Also, some style pointers. Use camel case starting with small letter for variables / fields. e.g. `totalPayout` instead of `TotalPayout`. etc.

Welcome to S.O. and java world and good luck further.

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to accept the answer (click the green tick) and upvote it if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `calculateSalary()`, which updates the total, but then you're calling `increaseHours()` after that, so `increaseHours()` also needs code that will update the total.

I would recommend not putting your TotalPayout calculation inside the constructor. Make a separate method for it (like you do for calculateSalary) and then you can call that method any time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

ther's a problem when you increase salary in the Payroll class, you don't update the totalPayout variable.

```
public void increaseHours(double x) {
    hours = x + hours;
    totalPayout += x * hourly_Rate;
}
```

I suggest you to check your code and don't use a static variable and method to sum all Payroll object (it's an object, not a utility class for payroll), you have some unused variable and, as Luud wrote, properties should be lower case, and so other stuff.